# Anki: How to style the [...] ellipsis in the Cloze text?

Tags: css, css-selectors, anki

I am styling an **Anki** card deck, and although by default the `[...]` in a Cloze type card is a different color, since wrapping it in a span to style the text, the ellipsis part is no longer differentiated.

This is the default:

`{{cloze:Text}}`

And for example, if I wrap it in a span:

`<span class="cloze">{{cloze:Text}}<span>`

and target it in the Styling section:

`.cloze {}`

The text becomes all the same color. It must mean there is another CSS selector for the ellipsis that I can't see. And I need to target that specifically if I want to customize the color.

[The manual](https://docs.ankiweb.net/templates/fields.html) mentions `#typeans` but I suspect this selector is for something else, because trying to target it hasn't worked for me at all.

How can the `[...]` be targeted so its text can be styled separately from the rest of `{{cloze:Text}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is kind of hackish, because I feel like I'm recreating functionality that *should* exist by default... but since it is very possible that the functionality *does not* exist by default (there may be no selector for targeting the `[...]`), I am using the technique posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/comments/7ijpn0/comment/dqzgudq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to add a new class (`cloze-collapsed`) as an HTML attribute.

In my example will also include my other related classes that influence the look of Cloze text (such as `cloze-equals`).

## For Cloze

To access these formatting options from the menu:

**Tools** → **Manage Note Type**

Click to select the "**Cloze**" type from the list.

Click the <kbd>Cards</kbd> button.

### Front Template (HTML & JavaScript)

```
<span class="cloze">{{cloze:Text}}</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("cloze")
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace("[...]", "<span class=\"cloze-collapsed\">[...]<\/span>")
</script>
```

### Back Template (HTML)

```
<span class="cloze">{{cloze:Text}}<span>
<br>
<br>
{{tts en_US voices=Apple_Victoria speed=1.1:cloze:Text}}
<br>
<hr id=answer>
<span class="back"><span class="cloze-only">{{cloze-only:Text}}</span> <span class="cloze-equals">=</span> {{Back Extra}}</span>
```

### Styling (CSS)

```
.cloze-equals {
    color: #ddd;
}
.card.nightMode .cloze-equals {
    color: #777;
}
/* cloze-collapsed class added as an HTML attribute using JavaScript */
.cloze-collapsed {
    color: #09c;
}
.card.nightMode .cloze-collapsed {
    color: #8df;
}

/* matching expanded colors to collapsed colors */
.cloze-only {
    color: #09c;
}
.card.nightMode .cloze-only {
    color: #8df;
}
```

I didn't change much. Just assigning the custom class with the script. remember to escape the `"` and `/` characters inside `<script>` with a backslash. Standard JS stuff.

If someone discovers a method that does not involve text replacement via JavaScript (like using a natively included selector instead - if there is one), I am still open to receiving answers.

Comment: I've found that targeting `[data-cloze]` in CSS usually works to style the cloze on the front card. (I'm here though because it's not working on one of my Android phones…)